# Converting linear algebra matrix form to summation form

Tags: linear-algebra, summation

I have the expression $UD(D^2 + \lambda I)^{-1}DU^Ty$ where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}, D \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}, y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$.

Apparently it is equivalent to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^p u_j \frac{d_j^2}{d_j^2 + \lambda}u_j^Ty
$$
where $u_j$ is the j-th column of $U$. Is this supposed to be obvious, or are there some middle steps to get the summation?

Edit: Realized I didn't provide sufficient info. $D$ is a diagonal matrix. $U$ is a matrix with orthonormal columns.

Comment: Let $M = D(D^2 + \lambda I)^{-1}D$. After computing the diagonal matrix $M$, Partition the matrix $U$ as
$$
U = \pmatrix{u_1 & \cdots & u_p}
$$
and compute the matrix product $UMU^T$ using [block-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication) multiplication.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I think my confusion is what occurs when you have the product of 3 matrices. It's intuitive for me how to write the summation form of the product of 2 matrices.